# NoSuchFieldException on getClass().getField()

Tags: java

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: id
```

The below line is creating the exception.

```
String fieldValue =String.valueOf(studyplanCategory.getClass().getField(filterProperty).get(studyplanCategory));
```

studyplanCategory is a valid object and has got actual values. Beacuse of this exception the load method and the search function in the LazyLoading DataTable of my JSF webapp is not working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

App fires up this exception because its doesn't see attribudes your want to give back.
Method getField() return non-private attribudes so if your attribudes are private, method doesn't see them. You can check http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/member/fieldTrouble.html

So you can do that your attribudes will change on protected or public and then should work it right. But this way (its same like example on primefaces) simulate real database.

```
public List<Car> load(int first, int pageSize, String sortField, SortOrder sortOrder, Map<String,String> filters) {  
        List<Car> data = new ArrayList<Car>();  

        //filter  
        for(Car car : datasource) {  
            boolean match = true;  

            for(Iterator<String> it = filters.keySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {  
                try {  
                    String filterProperty = it.next();  
                    String filterValue = filters.get(filterProperty);  
                    String fieldValue = String.valueOf(car.getClass().getField(filterProperty).get(car));  

...
```

So this list simulate real database only for example. If you want to use it. so you shoud do it on backing bean class and there do it. You open connection already with some filter or don't and then return data from database.

//EDIT: Man wrote that you should use getDeclaredField() but i did try this and it didn't work well, and throws up IlegalAccessException. When a pretype attribudes to protected, it works fine. I don't know why.

Comment: Hi But I got the exception even when trying protected.The Exception occured atjava.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class com.buddhiedge.server.model.StudyPlanLazyDataModel can not access a member of class com.buddhiedge.server.entity.StudyplanCategory with modifiers "protected"

Comment: Hi Its working public access specifier, though it is against the priciples that we should keep member fields of DATABASE TABLE(in this case) as private.

Comment: Man i had same problem but when a changed attributes to protected so IllegalAccessEception message wasn't more shown. So try change it to public. it should work. Perception already wrote solution like field.setAccessible(true); But later, try to do it in your backing bean class, in @PostConstruct you will create new LazyDataModel class and there u create statement for your database already with filter and statement will return to you filtered data, it's "lazy loading".

Answer (score 21):

From the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getField(java.lang.String)) for `Class.getField(...)`:

> Returns a Field object that reflects the specified public member field
>   of the class or interface represented by this Class object. The name
>   parameter is a String specifying the simple name of the desired field.
>   The field to be reflected is determined by the algorithm that follows.
>   Let C be the class represented by this object:
>
> If C declares a public field with the name specified, that is the
>   field to be reflected. If no field was found in step 1 above, this
>   algorithm is applied recursively to each direct superinterface of C.
>   The direct superinterfaces are searched in the order they were
>   declared. If no field was found in steps 1 and 2 above, and C has a
>   superclass S, then this algorithm is invoked recursively upon S. If C
>   has no superclass, then a NoSuchFieldException is thrown. See The Java
>   Language Specification, sections 8.2 and 8.3.

If the field you are trying to retrieve via:

```
studyplanCategory.getClass().getField(filterProperty)
```

is private, then you will get a `NoSuchFieldException`. For private fields, try this instead:

```
studyplanCategory.getClass().getDeclaredField(filterProperty)
```

And to get around potential illegal access exceptions when setting values via a field this way:

```
Field field = studyplanCategory.getClass().getDeclaredField(filterProperty);
field.setAccessible(true);
field.get(studyplanCategory);
```

Comment: Hi I tried that now the exception changed to java.lang.IllegalAccessException

Comment: Looks like you might have gotten around your problem already, but in any case see edits for how to get around the illegal access exception.

Answer (score 1):

Best solutions for `getClass().getField()` problem are:

Use **getDeclaredField**() instead of **getField**()

1)

```
String propertyName = "test";<br/>
Class.forName(this.getClass().getName()).getDeclaredField(propertyName);
```

2)

```
String propertyName = "name";<br/>
Replace **"HelloWorld"** with your class name<br/>
HelloWorld.class.getDeclaredField(propertyName)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same problem. My issue was my variables are not **public** . Make sure your class variables are **public**

```
  private Object getVariableValue(Object clazz, String variableName) {
    try {
        Field field = clazz.getClass().getField(variableName);
        return field.get(clazz);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        return "";
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        return "";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree that we should Use getDeclaredField() instead of getField()

```
 private Field getOwnProperty(Object clazz, String propertyName) {
    try {
        return clazz.getClass().getDeclaredField(propertyName);
    } catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
        log.warn( "Object has no property :  " + propertyName );
        return null;
    }
}
```